# ASP.Net Enter work as Tab in asp:content

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tabs, enter

I'm writing a little page, where you can scan the SN Code, the RMA Code and a Hardware Type with a bar code scanner. These scanner sends an 'enter' at last to change the line.
This 'enter' makes my page to try to send the page to the server.

So, is there any way to make the 'enter' work as an 'tab'??

I've found code like http://forums.asp.net/t/1088853.aspx?make+enter+key+work+as+tab+
but I don't have a head section or an body section. 
I work with asp:content.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Body` tag in master page a server side control using `runat="server"`.

in code behind of master page

```
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
public partial class MyMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public HtmlGenericControl BodyTag
    {
        get
        {
            return MasterPageBodyTag;
        }
        set
        {
            MasterPageBodyTag = value;
        }
    }
```

on content page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.BodyTag.Attributes.Add("onload", "enterToTab(event)");}
```

This is your solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19386/Adding-attributes-to-the-lt-body-tag-when-using-Ma).